# JQuery UI $.widget is not a function with autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the JQuery UI autocomplete combobox as described in http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

However, when I load the page I get:

> $.widget is not a function

and

> $("#UserContent").combobox(); is not a function,

Im loading JQuery v1.7.2 and JQuery UI v1.8.5 from googleapis.com. My widget code(for the combobox) is in a separate file.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: It's possible the external file with your widget code is being loaded before the jquery UI library.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing your combobox, instead of:

```
$("#UserContent").combobox();
```

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#UserContent").combobox();
})
```